# rndc sync -clean example.com on a DNSSEC singed zone

Tags: dns, sync, bind, ddns

I’vve got a DNSSEC singed zone with dynamic updates and automatic resigning. But if I run:

```
rndc sync -clean example.com
```

example.com.signed will be updated, but not the unsigned file where I add new entries.

Every 3 days I resign the zone to generate a new salt.

If I resign the zone without the dynamic changes synced, the will get deleted.

Is there a way to sync to the main, unsigned zonefile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to enable dnssec-secure-to-insecure with yes in the zone config part for the domain.
Than you have to unsign the zone with

> nsupdate -l
>
> update delete example.com. DNSKEY
>
> send
>
> quit

after that do the

> rndc sync -clean example.com

copy the example.com.zone.signed over to example.com.zone

now you can start editing and sign the zone again.